# How to use timer in jquery, while refreshing page in asp.net

Tags: jquery

I had JQuery plugin for timer in a asp.net page, I need to use it even when the page refreshes, but now the timer gets reset to 0 on page refresh. Anybody have any idea on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share what you tried so far.

Comment: If you use stop watch timer in your page,it get reset while you refreshing the page,now i understand that jquery varaibles are cleared once we refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery cannot fullfill your requirements because it refresh the all the client object whenever you refresh the page. You need a variable that should contain your timer value without caring what's going on (Refresh or server call etc).

So, you need a persistent variable (i.e. session variable) or can go with cookies as well. Update your cookie object using jquery and put the value from cookie rather than jQuery

Comment: Your answer is very useful for me, i made it by using cookies.